# Extend Azure Mobile Service: add MVC and new routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I had my azure mobile service running for a bit, and now I want to add a website to it, so I can host both a website and backend service from one machine in the azure cloud. I have added MVC and all relevant scaffolding like controller, view, and registered a route. The problem I'm having is that the new route that I added "/Home/Index" somehow is getting rerouted to startup azure web service page[image: azure default startup page]

These are the parts in the code that I've added.
Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:
[image: mvc view]

Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I feel like there is some mix up with the routes that are being added in the azure mobile service that is rerouting it to default page.

**UPDATE**
After moving to mobile app service using the guide I had to move all config into Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .AddTables(
            new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                .MapTableControllers()
                .AddEntityFramework())
            .MapApiControllers()
            .AddPushNotifications()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "default",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

So after doing all that I still see the default page and going to route "Home/Index" still shows this default page(showed above). I removed the `AddMobileAppHomeController()` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Startup.MobileApp.cs` file, you have this code:

```
new MobileAppConfiguration()
    .UseDefaultConfiguration()
    .ApplyTo(config);
```

The `UseDefaultConfiguration()` expands out to the following:

```
.AddTables(
    new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
        .MapTableControllers()
        .AddEntityFramework())
    .MapApiControllers()
    .AddMobileAppHomeController()
    .AddPushNotifications()
```

If you expand the call out as described, but remove the call to `AddMobileAppHomeController()`, your  MVC app will work (assuming the rest of your MVC stuff actually routes as expected).

Comment: I have updated my post, it looks like it's either a previous version of azure mobile backend scaffolding, or something else, but I don't have the piece of code you showed.

Comment: You seem to be using Azure Mobile Services SDK?  That doesn't mix well with MVC.  Azure Mobile Apps can work with MVC.

Comment: Is there a way to move from Azure Mobile Services SDK to Azure Mobile Apps?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-net-upgrading-from-mobile-services

Comment: Alright, so I did the upgrade/migration to app service, and now I have the config that you stated above, but it still shows the default page for any route I try.

Comment: Did you remove the `.AddMobileAppHomeController()`?  If you did, the default page is not even included and so can't be produced.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the `.AddMobileAppHomeController()` but it didn't help, I can still see this page displayed for any route I try in MVC and as default.